# Angular js Using with controllers how to change my div as replaced as another div on mouse over on a button?

Tags: angularjs

Angular js Using controllers. How to change my div as replaced as another div on mouseover on a button?

Comment: use ng-show and ng-hide concept. call the function on ng-mouseover="somefunction()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) or [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) or [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) combined with events directives [ng-mouseover](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover) or [ng-mouseenter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseenter) and [ng-mouseleave](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave)

```js
function SuperController($scope) {
 $scope.hovered = false;
}

angular.module('myApp', []);
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('SuperController', SuperController)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="SuperController as s">
    <button
      ng-mouseover="hovered=true"
      ng-mouseleave="hovered=false">HOVER ME</button>
    <div ng-if="hovered">Shown only if hovered</div>
    <div ng-if="!hovered">Shown only if not hovered</div>
  </div>
</div>
```